# Need help with Linux password

Tags: password-recovery

I'd like to find someone who can help me work around a password protected Linux system. This is not nefarious, it's an emergency situation. A friend has gone missing in the Vantana Wilderness. There may be info on his Linux system that would help locate him. I know very little about Linux, but PC proficient. Help anyone?

Comment: Be aware the procedure suggested above will NOT give you access to personal files, the very reason you may want to attempt that. If it were so simple we wouldn't use passwords.

Comment: You don't even need a password to access files on an unencrypted file system if you have physical access.  Just use a live session. (Try Ubuntu from installation media)

Answer (score 2):

You can always access the disk data - if not encrypted - with a so called "live" system.

Download a small [Xubunto ISO](http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/22.04/release/xubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso) and install it on a USB stick. There is a [documentation](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started) from Ubuntu on how to create a "live medium"

Boot the device from the usb - stick, select "Try Xubuntu" and open a file explorer when the desktop appears. Select some "external" disk (because your local "disk" ist the usb stick) and head to the directory `/home/????/` where `????` should be the user name of your friend.